# Play multiple instances in soundpool

Tags: java, android, soundpool

How do I play multiple instances of the same music placed in the code below? Also if I am playing 2 different sounds at once, where do I place that code?

```
public class SoundManager {

private SoundPool msoundPool;
private HashMap<Integer, Integer> mSoundPoolMap;
private AudioManager maudioManager;
private Context mContext;

public SoundManager()
{

}

public void initSounds(Context theContext)
{
    mContext=theContext;
    msoundPool=new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
    mSoundPoolMap=new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    maudioManager=(AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

}

public void addSounds(int Index,int soundId)
{
    mSoundPoolMap.put(1, msoundPool.load(mContext, soundId,1));
}

public void playSound(int index)
{
    int streamVolume=maudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    msoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(index), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1f);
}

public void playLoopedSound(int index)
{
    int streamVolume=maudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    msoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(index), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, -1,1f);
}
}
```

My main method is as follows: I have called this in the onCreate method

```
        m=new SoundManager();
    m.initSounds(getBaseContext());
    m.addSounds(1, R.raw.sound);
    Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button11);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            m.playSound(1);

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example code:

```
Music music = MusicFactory.createMusicFromAsset(pMusicManager, pContext, pAssetPath);
Music music2 = MusicFactory.createMusicFromAsset(pMusicManager, pContext, pAssetPath);

music.play;
music2.play;
```